# calcular cantidad y precio total especificado

Tags: php, html, css

estoy haciendo un pequeño ejercicio de compra de artículos, tengo la idea de como hacerlo funcionar, sin embargo, no consigo dar con la tecla para que me de el resultado del precio total del producto comprado. Estoy realizándolo en PHP, dejo por aquí el código. Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es que si compra 5 bolígrafos, pues que multiplique esos 0.50 x 5 y que me muestre el total a pagar. (obviad la variable $libreta, del final, pues aunque me multiplique el total de las libretas compradas, no consigo averiguar como hacerlo para el resto de productos).

```html
<h1>¡Bienvenido!</h1>

<form id="inicio" method="post" action="carrito.php">
    <p>
        <select name="articulo">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Libreta - 1.50€</option> 
            <option value="2">Boligrafo - 0.50€</option> 
            <option value="3">Grapadora - 3.00€</option>
            <option value="4">Tijera - 0.90€</option> 
            <option value="5">Carpeta - 0.20€</option> 
            <option value="6">Cartulina - 0.10€/option>
            <option value="7">Estuche - 5.00€</option>
         </select>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <label for="nombre">¿Cuantos quiere comprar?</label>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Añadir al carrito">
    </p>
```

```html
//INICIO DE LA SESIÓN
session_start();
$_SESSION["nombre"] = "Comprador";
echo "<p><b><u>Bienvenido $_SESSION[nombre]</u></b></p>";

//PRECIOS DE LOS ARTICULOS
$libreta = 1.50;
$boligrafo = 0.50;
$grapadora = 3.00;
$tijera = 0.90;
$carpeta = 0.20;
$cartulina = 0.10;
$estuche = 5.50;

//SELECCIÓN DEL ARTICULO A COMPRAR
if(isset($_SESSION['nombre'])==true) 
{
    if($_POST['articulo']==1)
    {
        echo "Articulo a comprar: Libreta";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==2)
    {
        echo "Articulo a comprar: Boligrafo";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==3)
    {
        echo "Articulo a comprar: Grapadora";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==4)
    {
        echo "Articulo a comprar: Tijera";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==5)
    {
        echo "Articulo a comprar: Carpeta";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==6)
    {
        echo "Articulo a comprar: Cartulina";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==7)
    {
        echo "Articulo a comprar: Estuche";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: su carrito esta vacio :(";
    }

    //CUANTAS CANTIDADES DEL ARTICULO VA A COMPRAR
      if(isset($_POST['number']))
      {
        if(!empty($_POST['number']))
        {
            echo "<br/>";
            $number=$_POST['number'];
            echo "Cantidad a comprar: " . $number;
        }

        else
        {
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "FALLO: Debe de seleccionar cuantos comprara.";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<a href='inicio.php'> Cancelar </a>";
        }
      }
}

//FACTURA

if (isset($_POST['articulo']) && isset($_POST['number']))
{
    echo "<br/>";

    echo "Total a pagar: " . $number * $libreta . " €.";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='pedidos.php'> gestionar pedido </a>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='inicio.php'> Volver </a>";
}


//SESIÓN NO INICIADA
else
{
    echo "no se ha iniciado la sesión";
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Fijate de guardar en una variable nueva a `$number * $libreta` y luego concatenarla en la muestra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He cambiado tu código para que funcione, pero aún así deberías revisarlo a fondo ya que hay muchas cosas "raras", por ejemplo he cambiado el primer echo para que concatene bien la variable y muestre su valor, antes debía estar fallando.
En cuanto a tu pregunta he cambiado fundamentalmente dos cosas, primer he cambiado el if else if ... por un switch así queda mucho más limpio y ordenado a, en cada case he añadido una variable precio con el valor del artículo seleccionado y en el apartado de factura multiplico el precio por el número de artículos, con esto debería funcionarte pero habría que darle una vuelta completa al planteamiento para que funcione todo de forma óptima (por ejemplo el último else creo que está fuera de sitio):

```
<?php
//INICIO DE LA SESIÓN
session_start();
$_SESSION["nombre"] = "Comprador";
echo "<p><b><u>Bienvenido". $_SESSION[nombre]."</u></b></p>";

//SELECCIÓN DEL ARTICULO A COMPRAR

if(isset($_SESSION['nombre'])==true) 
{
switch ($_POST['articulo']) {
case 1:
    $precio = 1.50;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Libreta";
    break;
case 2:
    $precio = 0.50;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Boligrafo";
    break;
case 3:
    $precio = 3.00;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Grapadora";
    break;
case 4:
    $precio = 0.90;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Tijera";
    break;
case 5:
    $precio = 0.20;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Carpeta";
    break;
case 6:
    $precio = 0.10;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Cartulina";
    break;
case 7:
    $precio = 5.50;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Estuche";
    break;
default
    $precio = 0;
    echo "ERROR: su carrito esta vacio :(";
}

//CUANTAS CANTIDADES DEL ARTICULO VA A COMPRAR
  if(isset($_POST['number']))
  {
    if(!empty($_POST['number']))
    {
        echo "<br/>";
        $number=$_POST['number'];
        echo "Cantidad a comprar: " . $number;
    }

    else
    {
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "FALLO: Debe de seleccionar cuantos comprara.";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a href='inicio.php'> Cancelar </a>";
    }
  }
}

//FACTURA

if (isset($precio) && isset($_POST['number']))
{
echo "<br/>";

echo "Total a pagar: " . $number * $precio . " €.";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='pedidos.php'> gestionar pedido </a>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='inicio.php'> Volver </a>";
}


//SESIÓN NO INICIADA
else
{
echo "no se ha iniciado la sesión";
}

?>
```